# Array Python [AJUDA]

Tags: python, array, python-3.x

Descrição:
Faça um programa que exibe a média entre o maior e o menor valor de um vetor de inteiros com vinte elementos dados pelo usuário e, ao final, exibe apenas os elementos que são maiores que a média.

Formato de entrada:
Vinte números inteiros, um por linha.

Formato de saída:
Na primeira linha, a frase "media: #" (sem aspas, em minúsculo, sem acentuação e com # substituído pela média dos números lidos e com duas casas decimais); nas linhas seguintes, os valores dados na entrada que sejam maiores do que a média, na mesma sequência que foram lidos e um por linha

Código que esta sendo utilizado:

```
arr = []
soma = 0
for p in range(20):
    x= int(input())
    arr.append(x)
    soma = soma + x

media = soma // len(arr)

if media < 0:
    print('media: 0.00')
else:
    print('media: %.2f' % media)

for b in range(20):
    if arr[b] > media:
        if arr[b] != 0:
            print(arr[b])
```

Quando eu envio, os dois primeiros casos de teste do programa, ele funciona, porém, os outros dois ultimos casos de teste, ele não funciona, e o programa não da dica do que está ocorrendo, acho que tem alguma parte errada, ou alguma gambiarra que eu tenha feito...

```
Entrada:
5
1
7
-6
-9
-6
0
-2
10
-6
-8
3
-4
-9
9
8
-7
3
-7
-10

Saída

media: 0.00
5
1
7
10
3
9
8
3
```

Comment: E no que precisa de ajuda?

Comment: nosso codigo nao esta funcionando!

Comment: arr = []
soma= 0
for _ in range(20):
    x = int(input())
    arr.append(x)
    soma = soma + x

media = soma // len(arr)

if media <= 0:
    print("media: 0.00")
else:
    print("media: %.2f" % media)
for b in range(20):
    if arr[b] > media:
        if arr[b] != 0:
            print(arr[b])

Comment: Edita a pergunta, adiciona o código e explique o que foi feito e o que está acontecendo atualmente.

Comment: as edições estão feitas!

Comment: **1)** Pede-se a média entre o maior e o menor valor da lista, não a média de todos; **2)** Por que é exibido 0 quando a média calculada for negativa? Não há no enunciado especificando isso; **3)** Por que utilizar `//` para calcular a média? Ela não deveria ser um número real? **4)** Por que, ao exibir os valores acima da média, é verificado se o valor é diferente de 0? Se for zero ele não deve ser exibido mesmo podendo estar acima da média? Também não diz no enunciado sobre isso.

Comment: Vou editar as entradas e saídas exemplares que o programa também da

Comment: E quanto às quatro perguntas do comentário anterior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi da descrição do problema, a média deve ser feita entre o valor máximo e o valor mínimo do vetor. Em seu programa você tenta fazer a média de todos os valores do vetor. Creio que o programa abaixo atenda a sua descrição:

```
vec = list()

for i in range(20):
    vec.append(int(input()))

media = (max(vec) + min(vec)) / 2

print("media: %.2f" % media)

for i in range(20):
    if vec[i] > media:
        print(vec[i])
```

Comment: MANOOOOOO VALEU!!!!!!

Comment: serio valeu muitoooo]

Comment: @Baria Fico feliz em ter ajudado.